# QThread destroyed in pyqtgraph on mac

Tags: python, qt, qthread, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to run this simple example I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/haiJsGhxTaQ/sTtMa195dHsJ), on MacOS X with Anaconda python.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import time

plt = pg.plot()

def update(data):
    plt.plot(data, clear=True)

class Thread(pg.QtCore.QThread):
    newData = pg.QtCore.Signal(object)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = pg.np.random.normal(size=100)
            # do NOT plot data from here!
            self.newData.emit(data)
            time.sleep(0.05)

thread = Thread()
thread.newData.connect(update)
thread.start()
```

However I keep getting:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is exiting immediately because you have given it nothing to do after it starts the thread. The error you see is because the thread is surprised that the main thread has exited without it.

Solution: add `QtGui.QApplication.exec_()` to the end of the script. Or, if you have PyQt (not PySide) you can run from an interactive python prompt instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `pyqtgraph.plot` method seems buggy to me (anyway, I wasn't able to get it to produce any useful output, but maybe I'm doing something wrong).

However, if I create a `PlotWidget` and set up the application "manually", it all works as expected:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time

app = pg.QtGui.QApplication([])
window = pg.QtGui.QMainWindow()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()
window.setCentralWidget(plot)
window.show()

def update(data):
    plot.plot(data, clear=True)

class Thread(pg.QtCore.QThread):
    newData = pg.QtCore.Signal(object)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = pg.np.random.normal(size=100)
            # do NOT plot data from here!
            self.newData.emit(data)
            time.sleep(0.05)

thread = Thread()
thread.newData.connect(update)
thread.start()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: ekhumoro: please share your experiences with pg.plot() in another SO question or on the pyqtgraph mailing list.

Comment: @Luke. I can't reproduce my earlier problems now, so I must have just been doing something wrong, somehow. Nevermind...

Answer (score -1):

When you call `QThread.start()`, that function returns immediately. What happens is,

1. Thread #1 - creates new thread, #2
2. Thread #2 is created
3. Thread #1 regains control and runs.
4. Thread #1 dies or `thread` variable is cleaned up by GC (garbage collector) - I'm assuming the 2nd scenario should not happen

To solve this, don't let the main thread die. Before it dies, clean up all threads.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html#wait

> bool QThread.wait (self, int msecs = ULONG_MAX)
>
> Blocks the thread until either of these conditions is met:
>
> - The thread associated with this QThread object has finished execution (i.e. when it returns from run()). This function will return
>     true if the thread has finished. It also returns true if the thread
>     has not been started yet.
> - time milliseconds has elapsed. If time is ULONG_MAX (the default), then the wait will never timeout (the thread must return from run()).
>     This function will return false if the wait timed out.
>
> This provides similar functionality to the POSIX pthread_join()
>   function.

So, add `thread.wait()` to your code.

NOTE: You will need to make sure that your thread quits. As is, it will never quit.

Comment: he doesn't have an event loop

Comment: The point is, you join the thread before you quit. Even when main event loop quits, you have to join your threads or you risk what he was asking about

Comment: I see your point. However: if the event loop IS started, then it seems to be unnecessary to wait on the threads. I'm not exactly sure why, given that the thread continues running after the event loop exits..

Comment: There is a race condition where thread is started but its thread storage is not initialized - that's what causing the error message from Qt. Nevertheless, not waiting for thread to finish before leaving main execution can cause problems elsewhere. In my answer I've *assumed* that anyone working with Qt already knows about things like QCoreApplication::exec(). It's only in every code example :)